# No editing toolbar

Tags: discussion, bug, status-completed

It appears something has broken, for me at least. The editing toolbar is currently not visible when posting a question or answer, yet if I edit an existing one it's fine. I tried FF, IE and Camino on Windows and Mac with the same problem. Anyone else have this issue or do I need to check further on my end?

Comment: I just vistited the new question page and I am seeing the toolbar on Chrome 8.0, and Firefox 3.6.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There was a short period where the editing toolbar was not working, however it was quickly fixed.  Please see [this post on MSO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77470/question-editing-tools-appear-to-have-died-hacked) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Nope, I seem to have the toolbar for answering...

Comment: And for asking a new question.